# Is it possible to show a matrix as a tree in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

This is a matrix and I want to know is it possible to show it as a tree in MATLAB?
It contains of two class (1 and 2) and every row would be a branch of a tree.

The zero in this matrix means there is nothing because of matrix length I used zero.

I used these functions on MATLAB but it seems I should write a custom one.

treeplot(A);

Matrix A:

```
10  13  0   1
10  13  22  1
10  22  0   1
13  22  0   1
17  26  0   1
4   12  0   2
4   12  15  2
4   15  0   2
7   12  0   2
7   12  15  2
7   15  0   2
12  15  0   2
12  15  17  2
15  17  0   2
```

As an example the first 4 lines of this matrix on the paper will be:

[image]

Comment: I think yes you can do that, [This is an Example of Morse Code Tree in Matlab](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/03/20/morse-code-binary-trees-and-graphs/), in similar way, you can rebuild your Matrix as a suitable graph to be represented later as a tree with Labels.

Comment: Looks like a pretty exotic format to store a tree, I guess you have to write your own function.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but you would have to do some preprocessing to somehow identify unique nodes. For example, how do we know that node `22` in row 3 is different from node `22` in rows 2 and 4? The output would likely be an edge list with node names, something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html#mw_f960304a-84a7-4cba-8606-1a6a6a385b0f).

Comment: I would suggest that instead of thinking of it as a tree, think of it as a graph with nodes and edges.  You will have to change your matrix to be just a list of the edges, and then you can plot: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html